Image of connected set by local diffeomorphism

Suppose $F:U\subset \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow V\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is $C^1$ and has $Df(u)$ an inversible operator for every $u\in U$. Assume $C\subset U$ is open, connnected, bounded with $\overline{C}\subset U$ and $F(\partial C)\subset \mathbb{R}^n\setminus C$. Show that $C\subseteq F(C)$ or $F(C)\cap C=\emptyset$.

I was able to solve this but I have no intuition about what is going on and I think I might have overlooked a simpler proof.
Here is what I have done:
Because $C\subset \overline{B(0,N)}$, then $\overline{C}$ is bounded and closed and so it must be compact. Because of continuity of $F$ then $F(\overline{C})$ is compact.
I claim that $\partial F(C)\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n\setminus C$.
Proof: Indeed, if $x\in \partial F(C)$, then $y=\lim F(c_n)$ where $c_n\in C\subseteq \overline{C}$. in particular, because $F(\overline{C})$ is closed (it is actually compact!), then $y\in F( \overline{C})=F(\partial C)\cup f(C)$. Thus $\partial F(C)\subseteq F(\partial C)\cup F(C)$. Because of the proof of the Inverse Function Theorem (now we use $DF(u)$ is invertible) $F$ is locally open and so $F(C)$ is open. This means that $F(C)\cap \partial F(C)=\emptyset$.  Thus, because $\partial F(C)\subseteq F(\partial C)\cup F(C)$, we actually need that $\partial F(C)\subseteq F(\partial C)\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n\setminus C$. $\square$
Now suppose that there is $c\in F(C)\cap C$ . $S=F(C)\cap C$ is open and nonempty. Also:
$$C=(C \cap F(C))\dot{\cup} (C\cap (\mathbb{R}^n\setminus F(C)))$$
However because $F(C)$ is open (again by the proof of the Inverse Function Theorem), we know $F(C)\cap \partial F(C)=\emptyset$ and this implies $\mathbb{R}^n=F(C)\dot{\cup}\partial F(C)\dot{\cup}(\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\overline{F(C)})$, so $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus F(C)= \partial F(C)\cup (\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \overline{F(C)}) $. Thus $(C\cap (\mathbb{R}^n\setminus F(C)))=(C\cap\partial F(C))\cup (C\cap(\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \overline{F(C)})) $. By the lemma, one of these is empty, namely $C\cap\partial F(C)$,  so $C\cap(\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \overline{F(C)})=\mathbb{R}^n\setminus F(C)$. Thus, we have :
$$C=(C \cap F(C))\dot{\cup} (C\cap(\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \overline{F(C)}))$$
Both of these are open and $C$ is connected by hypothesis. As the first set is nonempty: $C=C\cap F(C)\subseteq F(C)$ and from this we are done!

I can't see a question here.

@PaulFrost It is just that the hypothesis seem a bit random to me. I wouldn't expect this to be true... It took me a while to come up with this proof which doesn't seem very enlightening.

Indeed, I have overlooked a simpler solution. It is quicker and more illuminating to work with sequences. Clearly $F(C)\cap C$ is open, in particular it is open in $C$. Let us prove that it is closed in the topology of $C$. Let $\{c_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $F(C)\cap C$ converging to $c\in C$. In this case, we have that it is also given by $F(\tilde{c}_n)=c_n$ where $\tilde{c}_n$ is in $C$. Also, due to compactness of $\overline{C}$, we may extract a subsequence $c_{n_j}$ converging to a given $\tilde{c}\in \overline{C}=\partial C\cap C$. However, if $\tilde{c}\in \partial C $, then $F(\tilde{c})\in F(\partial C)\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n\setminus C$. But this is in clear contradiction with $F(\tilde{c})=c\in C$. Thus, $\tilde{c}\in C$ and $c= F(\tilde{c})\in F(C)$. Hence, $ c\in F(C)\cap C$ and so it must also be closed. By connectedness, $F(C)\cap C=C$
